# Is it possible to connect to docker db container by name in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have the following docker containers, which both share a network connection, and `exec`'ing into `api`, allows me to ping `db`, that bit is fine.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
8790d379ddb9        codeinsight/database   "/run-database.sh"       3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp             db
88b2022876cc        codeinsight/rest-api   "python /usr/src/a..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->8989/tcp   api
```

However, when connecting to `db` with sqlalchemy (probably not specific to the framework!) with:

```
self.engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user_name:password@db:3306/dbname', echo=True)
```

I get nothing but connection refused

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused`

So, is it possible to connect by container name when a link is defined and established? Or am I doing it incorrectly? Am completely new to docker, and will happily hear best practices etc. Thanks.

Comment: "Connection refused": it is a networking problem. Either the host called "db" is not the machine you expect it to be, or this host has multiple interfaces or ip addresses and mysql server is not listening on the interface/ip you are contacting. Please follow this steps to fix: 1) ping db and find the ip you're resolving. 2) confirm it is from the remote machine you expect. 3) connect in ssh to the remote machine and configure my.cnf's row "bind-address" to 0.0.0.0 (uncomment it, if it is). 4) try connecting again with the same syntax you used before.

Comment: 5) If it fails, ensure user_name and password pair can be used from the host you're connecting to, or edit the user on the remote mysql to use a wildcard "%" that means any host.